# What/Where is Thread Working Copy on physical device

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-14

From the java [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/Threads.doc.html):

> Every thread has a working memory in which it keeps its own working copy of variables that it must use or assign. As the thread executes a program, it operates on these working copies. The main memory contains the master copy of every variable. There are rules about when a thread is permitted or required to transfer the contents of its working copy of a variable into the master copy or vice versa.

What/Where is "Thread Working Copy"? Are they referring to CPU cache or RAM?

Reason for my confusion:

> For the purposes of this chapter, the verbs use, assign, load, store, lock, and unlock name actions that a thread can perform. The verbs read, write, lock, and unlock name actions that the main memory subsystem can perform.

Are they referring these instructions with assembly code?

Note: I know the specification is old and I tagged this question to Java 14. I did this because the construct still holds true.

**EDIT:**

I created the following image, can it be marked as correct?

[image]

---

This is what I understood. Please comment if there is anything wrong with the following image:

[image]

Comment: The fact is, what goes into RAM and what goes in the CPU cache is out of the control of software. It's the CPU that decides what goes where. The best software can do is to keep as little stuff as possible locally so there's a high chance that data will stay cached.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Federico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "working copy" is a logical construct, not a physical one.

The complete data of each thread will be found in RAM and parts of it might or might not exist as copies in the CPU caches depending on when they were last required by the CPU.

Comment: A value may also be held in a CPU register. Further, values can be merely implied by the program location. Most notably, a boolean value can be implied by the branch the program took, so there is no need to ever re-read the value within the branch.